# Qual é a forma mais correta : "Hoje faço 1 ano" ou "Faço hoje 1 ano" qual a forma mais correta? Nao deveria levar virgula : hoje, faco 1 ano

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, frases, advérbios, locuções-adverbias

Qual é a forma mais correta:
"Hoje faço 1 ano" ou "Faço hoje 1 ano"?
Não deveria levar vírgula:
"Hoje, faço 1 ano"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131752/discussion-on-question-by-clmend-qual-e-a-forma-mais-correta-hoje-faco-1-ano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambas estão corretas, embora a primeira forma seja mais informalmente comum.
E sim, "hoje, faço 1 ano" pode ou não ter a vírgula, de acordo com a ênfase na palavra hoje, ou nas palavras 1 ano